# Which one to select: Android Service or Intent Service or Async Task to Sync Files

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, synchronization

I wish to Sync or download multiple files from server on user demand in a native android app. I need to update UI about status of the Sync in progress as well. So in this case which of the below android component should be used.

- Service
- IntentService
- AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask` to do your background work and to update UI elements implement  `onProgressUpdate()` in your task. See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for details.

Comment: If I start Sync from one activity for couple of files using Async Task  and user navigates to another activity will Sync still work in background even if the Activity is in background or destroyed?

Comment: @nilMoBile It will continue until finished.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is completely independent from an activity so finishing activity does nothing to any task, unless you are cleaning your tasks by hand in `onDestroy()`. But, if an UI process your activity was running on is being killed by Android while your app is in the background, then your `AsyncTask` will be killed too as any other process's related object. Depending on size of your data you may need to bother or bother not. Your bigger problem would be orientation change that usually kills and recreates the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AsyncTask`, it is purposely built to do exactly what you are asking. That is

- Background work
- Notify UI during work.

All three options will work, but `AsyncTask` will be the easiest and best suited.

Answer (score 0):

I think that download files your needed with help Service or AsyncTask, and update UI make with help broadcast receiver.